# Why using batch to predict when applying Batch Normalization is cheating?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, training-data, batch-normalization

In a [post on Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-does-batch-normalization-behave-differently-at-training-time-and-test-time), someone says:

> At test time, the layer is supposed to see only one test data point at
>   a time, hence computing the mean / variance along a whole batch is
>   infeasible (and is cheating).

But as long as testing data have not been seen by the network during training isn't it ok to use several testing images?

I mean, our network as been train to predict using batches, so what is the issue with giving it batches?

If someone could explain what informations our network gets from batches that it is not suppose to have that would be great :)

Thank you

Comment: You may wish to take this over at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com), as this is more a pure machine learning question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But as long as testing data have not been seen by the network during training isn't it ok to use several testing images ?

First of all, it's ok to use batches for testing. Second, in test mode, `batchnorm` *doesn't compute* the mean or variance for the test batch. It takes the mean and variance it already has (let's call them `mu` and `sigma**2`), which are computed based solely on the training data. The result of batch norm in test mode is that all tensors `x` are normalized to `(x - mu) / sigma`.

> At test time, the layer is supposed to see only one test data point at a time, hence computing the mean / variance along a whole batch is infeasible (and is cheating)

I just skimmed through Quora discussion, may be this quote has a different context. But taken on its own, it's just *wrong*. No matter what the batch is, all tensors will go through the same transformation, because `mu` and `sigma` are not changed during testing, just like all other variables. So there's no cheating there.

Answer (score -1):

The claim is very simple, you train your model so it is useful for some task. And in classification the task is usually - you get **a data point** and you output the class, there is no batch. Of course in some practical applications you can have batches (say many images from the same user etc.). So that's it - it is **application dependent**, so if you want to claim something "in general" about the learning model you cannot make an assumption that during test time one has access to batches, that's all.

Comment: Okok that I understand it. But the guy say it is cheating as if giving batches during testing time improves the result. Is it ?

Comment: To some extent it might help, but usually everything that is not correct is considered cheating, whether it helps or not, as it simply makes results unreliable, that's all.